# Socket gets mysteriously removed from hashmap after sending a message

Tags: java, sockets, message

So im new to java sockets, and just started using them. The problem is: i have a client and a server application. The client wants to send some messages to another client. These messages will arrive to the server, and on serverside i put them in a queue, and check every 2 seconds if the destination client(socket) is alive. If so, then i will empty the queue and send every message to the specific client. Otherwise, the message is stored in the server application, until the destination socket is live.

Howewer, the main problem is that after the server deliveres the first message to the socket, the client(destination) socket disappears. I try to store these sockets in a hashmap. So after the first message has been sent, the hashmap gets empty somehow. And i cant deliver the rest of the messages.

I provide some of the code:

```
public class Server {
    
    public static volatile HashMap<Socket,String> clients;
    
    public Server(){
        clients = new HashMap<>();
    
    }
    
    
    public void start(){
        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000)){
            
            while(true){
            
                
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                
                new clientHandler(socket).start();
                
            }
 
        
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
    }
    
}
```

```
public class clientHandler extends Thread{
    
    private Socket socket;
    private Socket sendSocket;
    private Timer timer;
    private Queue<String> msgStack;
    private String socketName = "";
    
    
    public clientHandler(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        msgStack = new PriorityQueue<>();
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            
            while(true){
            
                String line = input.readLine();
               if(!line.contains("|") && line != null){
                    if(!isClientAdded(line)){
                        
                        Server.clients.put(socket, line);
                    }
                }else{
                    
                    System.out.println(line);
                    String[] msg = line.split("\\|");
                    
                    String fromUser = msg[0];
                    String toUser = msg[1];
                    String subject = msg[2];
                    String msgText = msg[3];
                    
                    if(isClientAdded(toUser)){
                        sendMsg(line);
                        if(timer.isRunning()){
                            timer.stop();
                        }
                    }else{
                        msgStack.add(line);
                        timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                System.out.println(msgStack+" "+msgStack.size());
                                if(isClientAdded(toUser)){
                                    if(!msgStack.isEmpty()){
                                        sendMsg(msgStack.poll());
                                        System.out.println("MSg: "+fromUser+" "+toUser+" "+subject+" "+msgText);
                                    }
                                    if(msgStack.isEmpty()){
                                        timer.stop();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Server.clients.remove(socket);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isClientAdded(String clientName){
        
        Iterator it = Server.clients.entrySet().iterator();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                            if(clientName.equals(pair.getValue()+"")){
                                return true;
                            }
                            it.remove(); 
                    }
        return false;
    }
    
    public void sendMsg(String send){
        
        String[] msg = send.split("\\|");
                    
        String fromUser = msg[0];
        String toUser = msg[1];
        String subject = msg[2];
        String msgText = msg[3];
        
        Iterator it = Server.clients.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                if((pair.getValue()+"").equals(toUser)){
                    
                    try {
                        socket = ((Socket)pair.getKey());
                        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                        output.println(fromUser+"|"+subject+"|"+msg);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                 
             it.remove(); 
        }
    }
    
}
```

I identify every socket from its pair "name". Thats how i know which socket i should sent the message.

Comment: You explicitly remove entries from the hashmap in isClientAdded, why?

Answer (score 0):

So yes, i got the problem, thanks to Rocco above in the comment section.  The problem was the it.remove() part. I copy/pasted this hashmap iteration code from an another project, because in my memory this hashmap iterator was just simple iterating, but it had an it.remove() at the end, for which i didn't remember.